# Split a row into multiple rows based on a column value db2

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following data:

```
Sr no....EMP_ID....Location...Period1....Value1....Period2....Value2....Period3....Value3
...1......Emp001....India........Salary.....10000.....Bonus.....1000.......Bonus code...AB
...2......Emp002....UK...........Salary.....20000.....Bonus.....2000.......Bonus code...CD
```

I want the output like this :

```
Sr no....EMP_ID....Location....Period...Value
....1......Emp001....India.......Salary.....10000
....2......Emp001....India.......Bonus.....1000
....3......Emp001....India.......Bonus Code.....AB
....4......Emp002....UK.......Salary.....20000
....5......Emp002....UK.......Bonus.....2000
....6......Emp002....UK.......Bonus Code.....CD
```

Comment: What database are you using, MySQL or DB2?  You should tag your questions accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This is an unpivot operation.  You can do what you want with a `union all`:

```
select EmpNo, Location, Period1 as period, Value1 as Value
from data
union all
select EmpNo, Location, Period2 as period, Value2 as Value
from data
union all
select EmpNo, Location, Period3 as period, Value3 as Value
from data;
```

Some databases have direct support for unpivot as well as other methods for doing it.  However, the above is ANSI standard SQL.

Comment: The only thing it will differ from OP's expected output will be `Sr no`.

Comment: what if i have thousands of employees..?

Comment: Then you'll get thousands of rows.  For thousands of rows, the `union all` should be reasonably efficient.