# i nf data table structure from json data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a database (mysql) table like

```
id |  party  |  rights    | m_id
---+---------+------------+---------
9  |abc      | 3,5,6      | ["12,","15,"6"]
20 |xyz      |  5,2       | ["6,","2,"9","12"]
21 |xyz 1    |  5,2       | ["6,","9,"12"]
```

Now I want to make my table in this way
search result for rights  5 is ["12,","15,"6"] ["6,","2,"12"] ["6,","9,"12"]

12  | abc , xyz,xyz1 |

15  | abc|

6   | abc , xyz,xyz1 |

9   | xyz,xyz1 |

Comment: "and so on belongs to party table" - wild guessing mode: There is a sql query involved somehere? If that matters, please add it to your question. If it does not, please provide the actual data (structure) you have available in your php script.

Comment: I have uploded image of table @VolkerK

Comment: Still confusing. At first you write "Right 5 contains three show id " and then "For eg: output right 9 : party2 ,party3.". Please elaborate. I could go into wild guessing mode: You're looking for all rows that have both a) `5` in the column `rights` _and_ `9` in the field `shows_id`? But that would immediately cause me to suggest a [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) ;-)

Comment: I took the liberty of re.writing your question (or what I currently think the question is.....). Please fill in the missing parts ....or edit it completely if I misunderstood the question (it's guess work anyway ;-)). In any case please take one thing from that edit: please, please, please post exisiting/sample data in a usable form. E.g. you can take the table in the question and paste it directly to the "Text to DDL" tool at http://sqlfiddle.com/ -> someone interested in the question can set up a test environment without too much trouble. Same with `var_export($x);` instead of var_dump($x).

Comment: rights 5  will show three json shows_id ["12","15","6"]

["6","9","11"]

["6","13","15","2","4","9"]    ... i want my output : shows_id 12 :  Percept               shows_id 15 : Percept , Tata Sky

Comment: Then please edit the question again and make the corrections there. Let's try to make it a "good question" text. I promise it will be to your benefit ;-)

Comment: I have edited Volkerk...Now the question is clear hope sooo

Comment: Terribly sorry, still not there. So, you have _one_ array containing _all_ the show_ids for all records having a 5 in `rights`? And `party2, party3` in the example output would actually be `Tata Sky, Tata Sky` because only the records having id=20 and id=21 have both rights~5 and show_ids~9?

Comment: But let's give it a try ...If I misunderstood something and therefore the answer doesn't help, just let me know.

Comment: You should not be storing multiple values in those two fields, and this is a fantastic example of why you shouldn't. As suggested by @VolkerK , your schema needs to be normalized.

Comment: I would have included a normalized version in my answer (one would guess I have too much time on hands right now, and one would be correct ;-) What a boring morning this is, yaaawn). But there were two assumptions about the data to make it somewhat meaningful, I wasn't willing to make here; so: just linked to the wiki entries.

Comment: It would be fine ..if it comes tata sky,tata sky for rights 5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942097/split-a-row-into-multiple-rows-based-on-a-column-value-db2

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with what I believe you already have. This is an [sscce](http://sscce.org/). If you adjust the mysql credentials it should run on your system, creating only a temporary MySQL table. It uses [PDO](http://docs.php.net/PDO) to access the MySQL server. Which API *you* actually use is not important (i.e. as long as the other API is mysqli, because the mysql_* functions [are depreacted](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) ;-))

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly', array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY=>false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
setup($pdo);

$statement = $pdo->prepare('
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        soFoo
    WHERE
        FIND_IN_SET(:right, rights)
');

$statement->execute( array(':right'=>5) );

/* in one way or another you have a loop where you fetch the records
having '5' in the `rights` field
*/
foreach( $statement as $row ) {
    echo $row['party'], ' ', $row['show_ids'], "\r\n";
}


function setup($pdo) {
    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soFoo
    (`id` int, `party` varchar(9), `exc` varchar(13), `rights` varchar(5), `show_ids` varchar(27))
   ');
  $pdo->exec( <<< eos
        INSERT INTO soFoo
            (`id`, `party`, `exc`, `rights`, `show_ids`)
        VALUES
            (9, 'Percept', 'Non-Exclusive', '3,5,6', '["12,","15,"6"]'),
            (20, 'Tata Sky', 'Non-Exclusive', '5,4,', '["6,","9,"11"]'),
            (21, 'Tata Sky', 'Exclusive', '5,4', '["6,","13","15,"2","4","9"]'),
            (22, 'Simbiotic', 'Exclusive', '6,2', '["12,","15,"1","6","7","8"]')
eos
    );
}
```

this prints

```
Percept ["12,","15,"6"]
Tata Sky ["6,","9,"11"]
Tata Sky ["6,","13","15,"2","4","9"]
```

and is (as I understand the question) as far as you've already got.

Now let's [decode the JSON array](http://docs.php.net/json_decode) and check [whether it contains](http://docs.php.net/in_array) the element `9`. If it does add inforamtion from the current row to an array called `$parties`

```
$parties = array();
/* in one way or another you have a loop where you fetch the records
having '5' in the `rights` field
*/
foreach( $statement as $row ) {
    $ids = json_decode($row['show_ids'], true);
    if ( in_array('9', $ids) ) {
        $parties[$row['id']] = $row['party'];
    }
}
var_export($parties);
```

prints

```
array (
  20 => 'Tata Sky',
  21 => 'Tata Sky',
)
```

But ... from a relational database point of view this is ....suboptimal.
The FIND_IN_SET clause hinders MySQL from using indices effectively; you're searching (compound) data *within* a single field. It's amazing what the database server implementations can do to improve performance; but it has limits.
And you're also transfering possibly unnecessary data from the MySQL server to the php instance (those records that have `5` in `rights` but not `9` in `show_ids`). If possible, this should be avoided. Networks/Network stacks are fast and can be optimized, RAM is cheap ...but again, there are limits.

So, I suggest you look into [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) on the one hand and/or [document-oriented databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) on the other hand.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give a example below so you can write in your way,

If you are having table below

```
id | name    
1  | a,b,c    
2  | b
```

and expected output like this

```
id | name    
1  | a    
1  | b    
1  | c    
2  | b
```

Then follow below solutions

If you can create a numbers table, that contains numbers from 1 to the maximum fields to split, you could use a solution like this:

```
select
  tablename.id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tablename.name, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) name
from
  numbers inner join tablename
  on CHAR_LENGTH(tablename.name)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(tablename.name, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
order by
  id, n
```

Please see fiddle [here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a213e4/1)

If you cannot create a table, then a solution can be this:

```
select
  tablename.id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tablename.name, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) name
from
  (select 1 n union all
   select 2 union all select 3 union all
   select 4 union all select 5) numbers INNER JOIN tablename
  on CHAR_LENGTH(tablename.name)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(tablename.name, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
order by
  id, n
```

an example fiddle is [here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a213e4/1)